# Creating a Matrix in MathDotNet given a 2D array

Tags: math.net

I have the following code got from [this](http://cgpp.net/csharp.xml) site as a download from [here](http://cgpp.net/file/Csharp2Dand3DTestbed.zip). The full path after the zip file is extracted would be some thing like E:\Csharp2Dand3DTestbed\GraphicsBook\LA\LA\MatrixTransform2.cs

```
protected static double[,] MatrixInverse(double[,] mat)
{
    Matrix m = new Matrix(mat);
    Matrix k = m.Inverse();
    return k;
}
```

But that does not compile. I see from [here](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix.html#Creating-Matrices-and-Vectors) that I need to do something like

```
protected static double[,] MatrixInverse(double[,] mat)
{
    Matrix<double> m = Matrix<double>.Build.WhatHere(???)(3, 4); // How with existing matrix
    Matrix k = m.Inverse();
    return k;
}
```

Can someone please guide me. I am not able to go further. I am using the latest version of the [Math.NET Numerics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MathNet.Numerics/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `double[,]` to matrix (two options):

```
var matrix = Matrix<double>.Build.DenseOfArray(array);
var matrix = CreateMatrix.DenseOfArray(array);
```

From matrix to `double[,]`:

```
var array = matrix.ToArray();
```

Note that these involve a full copy since matrices do not use 2D arrays internally. There are more examples on this in the [documentation](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix.html#Creating-Matrices-and-Vectors).